# Stored procedure stops running but recompile fixes it

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

I have a stored procedure that runs a few times a day in SQL Server 2016.

It is nothing more than a few selects that sum a value and count the records. It returns the values as output parameters.

Every so often, maybe once every two months it will just stop working. I will end up getting a time out issue when calling if from code (C#).

Normally it executes in less than one second. If I recompile it, everything returns to normal and I wont have another issue for months.

Any idea what could be causing this?

What additional information can I provide to assist in discovering the issue?

Here is a sample of one of the queries:

```
            SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spName] 
        @dateFrom as datetime,
        @dateTo as datetime,
        @CustID as varchar(50)
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        declare @TotalReturns as decimal(12,0),
                @TotalReturnsValue as decimal(12,2),

        --Total Transactions and Value for returns within date range
        --**********************************************************
        select @TotalReturns = count(*), @TotalReturnsValue = sum(cast(isnull([amountField],'0') as decimal(12,2)))
        from [tableName]
        where [customerField]=@CustID
            and [returnDateField] between @dateFrom and @dateTo
            and replace([amountField],' ', '') != '' 
         --**********************************************************

        --Outputs
        select isnull(@TotalReturns,0) as TotalReturns,
            isnull(@TotalReturnsValue,0) as TotalReturnsValue       
    END
```

Comment: You haven't shown relevant code, given us full error details, or any of the normal things one should include when they have an issue with their code.

Comment: I have heard see this issue on Oracle Stored procedures when the dba would update dev from prod.. but not in sql server.. can you ask the DBA where you are located

Comment: sounds like a lock caused the timeout issue, make sure there is no other queries running on the same target tables when that SP is running

Comment: A timeout can be caused by a _number_ of different reasons

Comment: Thanks for the down votes rather than trying to help.
I specifically asked what type of info would help.
I cannot provide you the exact query for security reasons and I stated that I am just getting a time out.
I have checked for locks and that does not seem to be the issue.

Comment: Yeah this could be a lot of different things. Less than optimal execution plan which was based on different parameters. This sounds like a probable candidate since you state that doing a recompile fixes it. This harkens back to parameter sniffing.

Comment: I wasn't one of your downvoters but almost certainly they are because you haven't provided much in the way of details. Could you post the procedure code?

Comment: Here is as much of the query as I can give.
select  count(*), sum(cast(isnull([amount],'0') as decimal(12,2)))
 from [tablename] 
 where [customer]=''
  and [ReturnDate] between '' and ''
  and replace([amount],' ', '') != ''

Comment: In the meantime you might have a peek here. It explains parameter sniffing quite nicely. Make sure you follow the links to view parts 2 & 3 also. https://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2007/11/27/parameter-sniffing/

Comment: Your "sample" query has no parameters at all. We can help but we are not magicians. Without the details all anybody can do is speculate.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to the the at parmeter name in the comment...

Comment: From the sample posted I would be shocked if the issue isn't parameter sniffing.

Comment: @SeanLange I think you may be onto something. Some of our customers have hundreds of thousands of records in that date range and some only have a few hundred. I read the article and I will do some of their suggestions. Please post and answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the sample query and the discussion in comments I am pretty sure this is related to parameter sniffing and sub-optimal plans based on data skew across clients and date ranges. You can read about parameter sniffing in depth here. https://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2007/11/27/parameter-sniffing/. Gail does a great job explaining the performance challenges with this and a number of ways to combat it.